# Trigger compiled but on firing gets ORA-01722 error

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ABC_TEST_TRIG 
BEFORE UPDATE ON ABC_TEST 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
NAME_CH VARCHAR2(25);
NUM_CH NUMBER(5);
BEGIN 
--SELECT NAME,NUM INTO NAME_CH, NUM_CH FROM ABC_TEST WHERE NAME ='KUNAL';

  INSERT INTO ABC_NEW (NEW_NAME,OLD_NAME,NEW_NUM,OLD_NUM)
    VALUES(':NEW.NEW_NAME',':OLD.NAME',':NEW.NEW_NUM',':OLD.NUM') ;
END; 
/

UPDATE ABC_TEST SET NAME ='KUSH' , NUM=90 WHERE NAME = 'KUNAL';
```

error:

```
UPDATE ABC_TEST SET NAME ='KUSH' , NUM=90 WHERE NAME = 'KUNAL'
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "APPSREAD.ABC_TEST_TRIG", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APPSREAD.ABC_TEST_TRIG'
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert has single quotes around all the values; `':NEW.NEW_NAME'` is a string literal. When you try to insert a string literal into a number column it tries to implicitly convert it, and obviously in this case that isn't possible. Whatever is in the old and new `NUM` columns is (presumably) actually a number, so `:OLD.NUM` is a number, the string literal `':OLD.NUM'` is not a number.

You just need to remove the single quotes:

```
  INSERT INTO ABC_NEW (NEW_NAME,OLD_NAME,NEW_NUM,OLD_NUM)
    VALUES(:NEW.NEW_NAME,:OLD.NAME,:NEW.NEW_NUM,:OLD.NUM) ;
```

or possibly more likely, without the `NEW_` prefixes on your columns:

```
  INSERT INTO ABC_NEW (NEW_NAME,OLD_NAME,NEW_NUM,OLD_NUM)
    VALUES(:NEW.NAME,:OLD.NAME,:NEW.NUM,:OLD.NUM) ;
```